# Inserting into postgres on heroku executes but doesn't stay

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

I have a connection with :

```
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=url.path[1:],
            user=url.username,
            password=url.password,
            host=url.hostname,
            port=url.port
        )
```

When I run the query to insert `self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Divers (email, hashpass) VALUES (%s, %s);",[email, password])` it returns successfully.

However, when I check my data the registration isn't there. When I run this query through the CLI it inserts but the incremented id is increased as if values had been inserted. Pleas help.

Comment: don't you need `self.cursos.commit()` or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows a `commit()` method [commit](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html). So you probably want to try using it like this:

```
self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, figured this out right before you commented!